# How to pass escaped string to shell script in Python

Tags: python

I am attempting to create a Python script that in turn runs the shell script "js2coffee" to convert some javascript into coffeescript.

From the command line I can run this, and get coffeescript back again...

`echo "var myNumber = 100;" | js2coffee`

What I need to do is use this same pattern from Python.

In Python, I've come to something like this:

```
command = "echo '" + myJavscript + "' | js2coffee"
result = os.popen(command).read()
```

This works sometimes, but there are issues related to special characters (mostly quotes, I think) not being properly escaped in the `myJavascript`. There has got to be a standard way of doing this. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the input stream of a process to feed it the data, that way you can avoid the shell and you don't need to escape your javascript. Additionally, you're not vulnerable to [shell injection](https://www.golemtechnologies.com/articles/shell-injection) attacks;

```
pr = subprocess.Popen(['js2coffee'], 
                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE,  
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result, stderrdata = pr.communicate('var myNumber = 100;')
```

Answer (score 1):

subprocess module is the way to go:
http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments

be kindly noted the following:

> args is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence of program arguments. Providing a sequence of arguments is generally preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file names)